# Drawing primitives on a Bitmap

Tags: android, drawing

In my custom view I have to draw on a base Bitmap when the user selects a flag. Suppose I have a base **face** bitmap and the user turns the **mustache flag** on. Since this custom View has to be scalable, I want to work with relative coordinates (in the range [0,1]) instead of bitmap width and height. The following doesn't work

```
Bitmap orig, face;

public void onDraw(Canvas c) {
  c.drawBitmap(face);
}

public void onMustacheFlag() {
  face = Bitmap.create(orig);
  Canvas c = new Canvas(face);
  c.save();
  c.scale(1f / face.getWidth(), 1f / face.getHeight());
  // Draw lines, circle, rectangles with all vertices in the range [0.0f, 1.0f]
  c.restore();
}
```

Also, this custom view forces height to be equal to width (it's a square form factor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters to `Canvas.scale(float, float)` serve as coefficients for `x` e and `y` coordinates in drawing routines. Passing `1f / width` means multiplying values assumed in the range (0, 1) by a number less then 1, thus the result of all drawing routines end up in the top left corner and is likely not visible. Instead, if I pass `width` and `height`, the code works as intended, because the range (0, 1) is mapped to (0, width):

```
public void onMustacheFlag() {
  face = Bitmap.create(orig);
  Canvas c = new Canvas(face);
  c.save();
  c.scale(face.getWidth(), face.getHeight()); // instead of 1 / width
  // Draw lines, circle, rectangles with all vertices in the range [0.0f, 1.0f]
  c.restore();
}
```